# shell script stops running after bash -l

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I am new to shell scripting and I have created a `run_all.sh` file with the following content,

```
cd directory1/folder1
bash -l
conda activate py38
poetry install 
./scripts/run_myscript.sh
```

If I execute these line one by one in terminal I have no issues but when I put all in `run_all.sh` file and execute (`bash run_all.sh`), only the first two lines gets executed and then it stops without printing any error code.

**Note:** I am using Sagemaker which uses `sh` as the default shell and not `bash` so in manual run I start new shell (`bash -l`) to activate py38 through conda (`conda activate py38`) and install the requirements ...

Please let me know if you see what I am missing here.

Comment: What is your understanding of the function `bash -l` does?

Comment: `bash -l` is starting a new shell - are you sure you really want to do that?

Comment: @Mike : Type `exit`, or a lone Control-D, and it will continue to run.

Comment: @CarlNorum, sagemaker's default shell is uses `sh` and not `bash` so in manual run I start new shell to activate py38 through conda and install the requirements ...

Comment: It might work if you you eliminate that `bash` -l` and then change the first line of the script to `#!/bin/bash` . In any case and to agree with highly voted comments above, it's not clear what/why you need `bash -l` . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Man oh man.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd directory1/folder1 && conda activate py38 && poetry install && ./scripts/run_myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

If `sh` is your default shell and you want bash, change your script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
cd directory1/folder1
conda activate py38
poetry install 
./scripts/run_myscript.sh
```